# punching shear not shown

Tags: structural-engineering

i have modeled a mat foundation as shown. some of column area failed on punching shear as shown. i provided drop on those reasons. it improved punching shear value but still some drop panels punching value is not displayed. again i provided drop panel over the mat and checked the punching shear. in this case the punching value was shown everywhere but the soil pressure increased.

should i model drop over the mat? or is there any modeling error coz of which some punching value was not shown. Also the soil pressure is similar in both cases plz help me someone. thanks.
[image: overlapped condition punching)][image: non overlapped condition punching]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  What modeling software are yo using? Are you asking about how the program is working or how to design the foundation?  Have you done hand calculations to check that your model is giving reasonable results?

Comment: You shall read the manual and test drive the program with a hand-cal verifiable problem before performing full-scale analysis.